# I can not find the data from link in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I try to make linke and when I click to that link I want to get some data from database in new page (`details.php`)  but when I try to do this the (`details.php`)page it open empty without anything!!

the link code is:

```
         <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' sytle='float:left;'>Details</a>
```

and the php code in details.php page is:

```
<?php


    if(isset($_Get['pro_id'])){

        $Product_id= $_Get['pro_id'];

    $get_pro= "select * from products where Product_id = '$Product_id'";

 $run_pro= mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);

 while($row_pro= mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

     $pro_id=$row_pro['Product_id'];
     $pro_title=$row_pro['Product_title'];
     $pro_price=$row_pro['Product_price'];
     $pro_image=$row_pro['Product_image'];
     $pro_desc=$row_pro['Product_desc'];

     echo "

     <div id='single_product'>

     <h3>$pro_title</h3>

     <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='400px' height='300px' />

     <p><b> Price  $pro_price RO</b></p>

     <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id' sytle='float:left;'>Go Back</a>

     <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right';>Add to Cart</button></a>

     </div>
     ";

 }
    }


 ?>
```

Ican not find where is my mistake

Comment: should be using prepared statements or sanitizing what you query from the db

Comment: Check your error logs, is the status code of the page a 500? Is `<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' ` in a PHP echo? Also SQL injection hole you have.

Comment: `$_Get` is wrong. It should get `$_GET`. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: Also you should use "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" as offered by the `mysqli` extension to prevent sql injection vulnerability which your code currently shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are case sensitive in PHP and the correct name for the get array is `$_GET` so amend you code like this

```
if(isset($_GET['pro_id'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention because variables in PHP are key sensitive, so `$_Get[]` array doesn't exists. Try to replace it with `$_GET[]`.